# Benefits of Combining reducers

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Since I am pretty new to the environment of `Redux` I have come across the tutorials that I follow that the instructor created multiple reducers for each state and at the end combined them using `combineReducers` example is in the code below. I want to know why is it necessary to combine multiple reducers for handling large applications

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux"; 
import { Dishes } from "./dishes";            //These are the constant variable from different                                                                                      
import { Comments } from "./comments";        //files where the Reducers are located
import { Promotions } from "./promotions";
import { Leaders } from "./leaders";

export const ConfigureStore = () => { //CREATE the store here
    const store = createStore(
       combineReducers({       //we show how exactly various reducers combine
           dishes: Dishes,     //dishes managed by Dishes
           comments: Comments,
           promotions: Promotions,
           leaders: Leaders
                                //recomposition of global state in our application

       })
    );

    return store; //created the store
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`combineReducers` provides you the flexibility divide your state logic into smaller chunks or reducers and focussing on specific behaviours or data in that specific reducer.

For example, in the above you have Dishes, comments, Promotions and Leaders reducers.

Each reducer is independent and will only be concerned about handling its own data rather than having complex state in a single reducer and coagulating all of the logic for each update in a single reducer

Also separating out logic in multiple reducers will help you **achieve a simpler state format** which will make it easier for you to maintain updates

Also it helps in **performance optimizations** because if the same reducer was storing all the data in itself, to update a deeply nested state, you would have cloned the rest of the data and it would mean a lot of reference comparisons will fail

Comment: Your description helped a lot, Thanks a bunch @Shubham_Khatri